# SOAP using C#

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap

How do you use SOAP using C#?  Is there a simple, yet effective tutorial for this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

SOAP is encapsulated with the Web Service model in ASP.Net.  Here's a good intro article on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972326.aspx

You can find some good tutorials on MSDN and at the ASP.Net web site.  Here's a great introductory video:  http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-7025.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I like the tutorial at http://users.skynet.be/pascalbotte/rcx-ws-doc/dotnet.htm

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Visual Studio ?

In VS2008 you can add a "Service Reference"
http://www.techtoolblog.com/archives/add-web-references-to-visual-studio-2008

(Google really is your friend on this one :p)