# Passing a Complex Type as a Parameter to an ASMX Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am trying to write a simple ASMX web service in C#. For the life of me, I can't understand or find out how to accept more complex parameters than primitives.

Is it possible to do something like:

```
[WebMethod]
public string MyMethod(SomeStruct parameter)
{
}
```

Comment: Article on complex types with ASMX. http://encosia.com/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/. I would suggest moving to WCF and use SVC instead

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: More importantly, why are you using ASMX? Are you stuck at .NET 2.0?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Depends on what you're using ASMX for. For simple endpoints that are only called from JavaScript, WCF is a dog compared to ASMX (or even an HttpHandler, for that matter). Between the config hassle and DataContractJsonSerializer's shortcomings, pushing people to "upgrade" to WCF when ASMX already does what they need is not helpful. Especially with Web API right around the corner.

Comment: @DaveWard: update your information set. Have you looked at WCF in .NET 4.0? Almost nothing in the config file by default. ASMX is "legacy" according to Microsoft and is not even getting bugs fixed.

Comment: I'm just using ASMX because it seemed simpler to setup, it is a very basic service

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I work with WCF regularly in situations where its additional flexibility is needed (but ASMX vs. WCF is in no way relevant to the OP's question). WCF is definitely still a dog for web work in 4.0, which is why it has continued to see such low adoption and Web API was necessary.

Comment: See http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/07/03/microsoft-says-asmx-web-services-are-a-%E2%80%9Clegacy-technology%E2%80%9D/ and decide for yourself. I've decided to recommend against creating new code in a technology that the vendor doesn't support by fixing bugs.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: There haven't been any bugfixes for HttpHandlers in years either...  because neither have *needed* bugfixes for what they're good for. Making assumptions based on MSDN docs is a pretty far stretch. Especially considering that Add New Item > Web Service is still present and pointing to the ASMX template in not only VS2010 *but also the new VS11 developer preview*. Regardless, it will be a moot issue soon enough since Web API is so much better than both ASMX and the current state of WCF.

Comment: @DaveWard: I'm not making assumptions. See https://mvp.support.microsoft.com/profile/John.Saunders and figure it out.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: If that's all it takes, then... https://mvp.support.microsoft.com/profile/Dave.Ward

Comment: @DaveWard: you've missed my point. I mean I'm not guessing. You can surely guess that I might have NDA information on this topic. I'll see if I can find a stronger public statement. Among other things, I've seen a public statement that "only the most critical security fixes" are being made to XML Serialization, which ASMX depends on. I also didn't say, "don't use it at all", I said evaluate the facts and decide. I've decided against it, pretty much like I've decided against VB6.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: For use with JavaScript and browsers (which is all I'm talking about if you look back to the first comment), XML serialization never comes into play. It's all JavaScriptSerializer. Meanwhile, WCF's active development hasn't been enough to get DataContractJsonSerializer on par with JavaScriptSerializer (and consequently ASMX) in the meantime. NDA information or not, you would be doing someone a disservice to encourage a move from ASMX to WCF right before Web API comes out.

Comment: But, Dave, the OP said nothing about consuming the service from a JavaScript client. And, besides, [Web API](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20HTTP) is not ASMX. Thanks for mentioning it, but it seems more important to me to shatter the complaisance of those sticking to ASMX, than, well, just about anything else. They need to drop the idea that "It ain't broke"

Comment: @DaveWard: See also [More Reasons to Not use ASMX Services in New Code](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2011/12/07/more-reasons-to-not-use-asmx-services-in-new-code/). Feel free to comment there.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: That's why I specifically started out by saying it depends on whether he's using it for a client-side callback or something else where WCF does make sense. I never claimed that Web API is ASMX, but it's a departure from the current WCF approach too. It would be a pointless exercise to move from ASMX to WCF now instead of moving directly to Web API next year. If you're focusing on "connected systems", where WCF is actually a big improvement over ASMX, you may not realize that WCF is currently a step backwards for client-side work. It's not just a matter of "ASMX ain't broke".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else having the same question. The answer was to use [Soap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885883/soap-using-c-sharp).

As to why use ASMX service instead of WCF, there are a couple reasons:

1. Easier to configure and deploy for a *small* web service
2. Other developers are using and expect ASMX services

While the first reason is arguable, there really is nothing that can be done in the short term about the second reason, especially in the context of working with developers outside your own company.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
[WebMethod]
public string MyMethod( )
{
   var parameter = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<SomeStruct>(HttpContext.Current.Request["parameter"]);
}
```