# Error WebService ASMX with different return types

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I have two methods inside an ASMX web service like this:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[ScriptService]
public class TestWs: WebService
{
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false)]
    public void Method_1()
    {
        //Do Something
    }

    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false)]
    public long Method_2(ParameterClass paramClass)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

When I try to call one of these methods using AJAX, it returns the follows error:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerType..ctor(Type type)
>   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()
>   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)

But when I change the return type of *Method_2* to *void*, everything works fine.
Why it is happening? How can I fix it without change the return type?

---

**UPDATE**
There's another difference between these two methods: one recive a class as parameter and the other don't recive any parameter. When I remove the parameter from *Method_2*, it works too.

**UPDATE 2**
I changed *Method_2* to:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false)]
public long Method_2(string paramString)
{
    ParameterClass pClass = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<ParameterClass>(paramString);
    //Do Something.
    return 0;
}
```

It works this way, but I still without know why it occurs.

Comment: What is the stack trace of this error? What line throws it?

Comment: It's there now. I edit the question

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this post might help you, having complex parameters as inputs to your web service will pose issues.

[Passing a Complex Type as a Parameter to an ASMX Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423077/passing-a-complex-type-as-a-parameter-to-an-asmx-service)

Comment: The only solution I have found was to use SOAP or, to avoid that, I just did what I wrote on Update 2. But I don't understand why  it is happening.

Comment: MSDN doesn't maintain the documentation for ASMX anymore, but a webmethod  just doesn't allow complex classes only native types.  Most likely due to serialization of that object. [Here's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ef803zd(v=vs.90).aspx) the MSDN documentation on WebMethods.

Comment: If webmethods doesn't allow complex classes, why when I change the return type to void instead long (or any other type) everything works fine (except that I need the webmethod return value on my JS)?