# Web API to insert records

Tags: c#, vb.net, asp.net-web-api

I am working on Taleo web API. I have an XML file with several records that I will have to insert into the Taleo system using its web API.

I have got the Taleo API guide from http://tbe.taleo.net/products/TBE_API_Guide.pdf.

For the first time, I am working on web API so I don't know where to start. Although the guide shows some examples using SOAP, I don't know how to make this request and retrieve the response using C# or VB.NET. I googled it but didn't get much information about it. If you share your ideas, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SOAP using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885883/soap-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

From the PDF, it appears the WSDL for the service is at: http://tbe.taleo.net/wsdl/WebAPI.wsdl.  In your C#/VB project, use the "Add Service Reference" option on the context menu and supply that URI to the WSDL.  That will generate a proxy and many ancillary classes on which you can call whatever methods you need - the SOAP details are under the covers.  You'll instantiate an instance of WebAPIClient and should see all the relevant methods there.

For example, in C# after creating a new Service Reference with (uninspired) namespace name of ServiceReference2, I can code the following (though I have no idea what it does!):

```
        var x = new ServiceReference2.WebAPIClient();  // I suspect there's an overload expecting credentials
        ServiceReference2.AccountBean y = x.getAccountById("bar", 0);
```

Exception handling is left to the reader :)