# sending SOAP request in asp.net mvc3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, soap

I want to send following SOAP/XML request and get the SOAP response back in asp.net mvc/C#

```
<?xml
<soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:urn="urn:myurn">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:fLocHistory 
soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <HistRequest 
xsi:type="urn:SubMemLocationHistoryRequest">
            <MSID xsi:type="xsd:string">test</MSID>
            <AID xsi:type="xsd:int">2</AID>
            <MemMSISDN xsi:type="xsd:string">test</MemMSISDN>

         </HistRequest>
      </urn:fLocHistory>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

What is the better way to send request. I have seen example regarding `MSXML2`, `WCF` or `asmx`. If you could point some good starting tutorial. I have seen some examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972326.aspx) and [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/building-35-applications/an-introduction-to-soap-based-web-services-with-visual-web-developer-2008) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885883/soap-using-c-sharp).

Comment: Have you tried just adding a service reference and pointing it at the wsdl file?  That works for many web services and hides all of the soap  calls from your code.

Comment: I don't have any wsdl file. I am told to send the request in above format and i will get back the response