# C# Client-Server Time Tracker: How should I implement the networking?

Tags: c#, networking, client-server

I'm writing an application in C# that allows people to track the amount of time they spend on tasks. It can be used by a single person to track their own personal time, but it will also be able to work in, for example, a company - like, if they want to track the amount of time spend on some project.

The data being stored by this program is pretty simple - a collection of all the tasks and each "block" of time that was spent on it (including date, start/stop time, and length of time spent).

For the multiuser functionality, my plan was to have a single server that the clients send updates to the tracked time. I don't think the clients will need a continuous connection as the updates would typically be pretty far apart.

<strike>Additionally, as both the server and the client will store a copy of the data, either of them can ask for a copy from the other if there's a data loss on either.</strike> Femaref has informed me that this is a poor idea, so I've removed it.

So, my question is, how should I approach this? I've seen some C# client/server tutorials, but those seem to be geared towards continuous connections.

Comment: Having both the client and the server as an authorative source for the data is really bad. Only the server should have the authority over the data, and that data is regulary backuped.

Comment: Can't it be a simple web application to which users can upload their working hours?

Comment: @Femaref: Hmm, that's a good point. I'll take that out of the plans.

Comment: The problem with letting users report there own time(and not keeping it server side) , is your trusting what ever they put in(even if your app, doesn't allow it)

Comment: @user428955: I'm not quite sure how the users wouldn't be putting it in themselves. Perhaps I don't understand what you mean...

Comment: For systems that are tracking reported hours, you don't want john Doe, to be able to enter time for Sam smith. So you want some mechanism, to confirm the person is who they say they are. My answer hopefully should give you more details. What server side database are you planning to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to track the data separately. First Allow users to track there own time, and just store that in a local db (you can use something like csharp-sqlite ), then when the user connects sync what data you want to keep on server.

For data that you want to track sever side your just going to want the app to sign in and say its starting a task and then sign out when its stopping a task(then have the server side hit the db functions)(your going to want to keep the user data, and the server data separate, so you know what you can trust, and what implications there are for using what data ) .

Obviously, your going to want to handle situations where a task goes on longer then expected. For example someone forgets to say there done with the task(like there computer just crashes)(you can do this by having your app just say its still working on a task every so often).

The best way I have found to get around issues that are caused by trusting peoples input is to just tie into something like your local A.D or LDAP and allow management control(because in the end they are the ones that sort out any messes that come from people having the wrong hours) thats all handled server side. If you don't have A.D or LDAP, you might have to consider implementing some kind of RSA key mechanism for authentication and authority chains.

For talking to the server side process on the client, I suggest something like SOAP ([SOAP using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885883/soap-using-c-sharp)). That way you can move your server language to what ever makes your feel all warm and fuzzy.

This is a bit of a broad question so its hard to cover everything, but it should give you some leads in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks! One question - what if the connection is lost while the server is tracking the task? I'm guessing something like, upon reconnection, the server asks the client if the task was going on, and if it says yes, the server logs the difference?

Comment: I don't think your going to want to ask the client what happened, because that means you have to trust what the client says, which can get a bit messy(and lead to trusting something you dont want to). If you have the client reporting every 5 minutes, you can have your server stop any tasks that the client hasn't reported in every 10 minutes. So at most your missing 10 minutes of data if something goes wrong. You can also have the client pop up say it hasn't been able to report its work, and then switch over to a user recorded task, as I talked about earlier.